Intraday OHLC chart with KX Developer
I'm trying to use the grammar of graphics plotting library in KX developer 1.5.4 to plot a 1 min chart for IBM. However, as you can see I get disjointed candles, which seem to have each collapsed into their respective days. How can i plot continuous intraday bars?
ohlc:get `:tickers/ibm1; / 1 minute IBM data
ohlc:update gain: (close > open) from ohlc;

candlestick : {
    fillscale : .gg.scale.colour.cat 01b!(.gg.colour.Red; .gg.colour.Green);

    .qp.theme[enlist[`legend_use]!enlist 0b]
    .qp.stack (
        // open/close
       .qp.interval[x; `time; `open; `close]
            .qp.s.aes[`fill; `gain]
            , .qp.s.scale[`fill; fillscale]
            , .qp.s.geom[`gap`colour!(0; .gg.colour.White)];
        // low/high
        .qp.segment[x; `time; `high; `time; `low]
            .qp.s.aes[`fill; `gain]
            , .qp.s.scale[`fill; fillscale]
            , .qp.s.geom[enlist [`size]!enlist 1])
    };

.qp.go[700;300]
    .qp.theme[.gg.theme.clean]
    .qp.title["Candlestick chart"]
    candlestick ohlc

The candlestick function is adapted from Candlesticks.

